# When does a commutative DGA have a finitely generated quasi-free resolution?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, differential-graded-algebras

Suppose that $A$ is a commutative dg-algebra (say over base $k$) which is bounded in non-positive degree (with cochain complex conventions). There exists a quasi-free resolution of $A$. My question is, under what conditions on $A$ does $A$ admit a quasi-free resolution which is *also* finitely generated (as a graded commutative algebra). Can we completely characterize such algebras intrinsically?

Comment: Compact objects in the homotopy category maybe?